# shouldOverrideUrlLoading's URL and onPageFinished's URL are different

Tags: android, webview

I'm making auto search program.

Please see the code first.

synchronizedLoadUrl : call loadurl and wait until onpagefinished called

```
private String search(AutoClickItem item) throws InterruptedException {
    this.synchronizedLoadUrl("http://m.naver.com");
    this.loadUrl("javascript:" + querySelector("#query") + ".click();");
    this.loadUrl("javascript:void(" + querySelector("#query") + ".value = '" + item.query + "');");
    this.loadUrl("javascript:" + querySelector("button[type=submit]") + ".click();"); // this calls submit() and move to another location.

    return pageFinishedQueue.take();
}

public class AutoClickWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
BlockingQueue<String> pageFinishedQueue;

public AutoClickWebViewClient(BlockingQueue<String> pageFinishedQueue) {
    this.pageFinishedQueue = pageFinishedQueue;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    pageFinishedQueue.add(url);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
}
```

The process when I run this code:

first, onPageFinished fired with "m.naver.com"

second, shouldOverrideUrlLoading fired with "m.search.naver.com/search.naver?query=%EC%95%84%EC%9A%B0&where=m"

because I called `"this.loadUrl("javascript:" + querySelector("button[type=submit]") + ".click();");`

third, onPageFinished fired with "http://m.naver.com" < problem

I can't understand why third onPageFinished fired with "http://m.naver.com"

The webview is showing "m.search.naver.com/search.naver?query=%EC%95%84%EC%9A%B0&where=m" but onPageFinished fired with "m.naver.com" !!

I want to know why it works like this and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)):

> **Returns:** True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

It sounds like you are not leaving the WebView, so you should return false.